# sscanf parsing value inside square brackets

Tags: c++

I'm trying to parse value inside  square brackets:

MYVAR[3]

```
std::string key("MYVAR[3]");

int idx;
int result = sscanf(key.c_str(), "%*s[%i]", &idx);
if (result > 0)
{
    std::cout << "It's array value" << std::endl;
}
```

How can  I do this?

Comment: Why are you casting to `char *`? `sscanf` takes a `const char *`, which is exactly what `std::string.c_str()` returns

Comment: I didn't notice. My mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%*s` will read the character `[`, so you should use specifier `"%*[^[][%i]"` to stop before the character.

Comment: Oh thank you! It worked. I was trying to figure it out for 1 hour and eventually I gave up and asked here. By the way do you think sscanf is a good way to do this? I need to parse simple configuration file in format VARNAME=VALUE and VARTABLE[INDEX]=VALUE.

Comment: 1 hour is not a very long time to try figuring it out before asking for help.

Answer (score 1):

`"MYVAR[3"` and `"MYVAR[3]"` will both provide the same result.

```
int result = sscanf(key.c_str(), some_format, &idx);
if (result > 0)
```

IOWs, content after the integer is irrelevant/not checked as `sscanf()` is not used to parse *inside square brackets*.

Code should check that both brackets exist.

---

Many approaches exist.  Suggest using `"%n"` to detect scan completion.

```
#define FMT_NOT_LBRACKET "%*[^[]"
#define FMT_BRACKETED_INT "[%i]"
int idx;
int n = 0;
sscanf(key.c_str(), FMT_NOT_LBRACKET FMT_BRACKETED_INT "%n", &idx, &n);
if (n) {
  Success();
}
```